# Django: unable to make a calculation inside a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I've created a e-commerce Django application  and in the back office of this application, I have a page that is supposed to show some statisctics.
I'm trying to display benefits or losses.
For the costs, I've created a @property in the model as following:

```
class Statistics(models.Model):
    """
    The Statistics model represents the statistics that can be calculated
    """
    costs_infra = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Costs Infrastructure")
    costs_salary = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Costs Salary")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Statistics"   

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Statistics"""

        return " Infra costs: {}, Salary costs: {}".format(
                self.costs_infra,
                self.costs_salary
            )
    
    @property
    def calculate_costs(self):
        return self.costs_infra + self.costs_salary
```

For the total income, I've calculated it inside a view as following:

```
@group_required('Administrator', 'Manager')
def stats_home(request):

    total_users = User.objects.all().count()
    costs = Statistics.objects.all()
    subscriptions_1month = Subscription.objects.get(plan_name='1 Month')
    subscriptions_1year = Subscription.objects.get(plan_name='1 Year')
    subscriptions_3year = Subscription.objects.get(plan_name='3 Years')
    user_subscriptions_1month = UserSubscription.objects.filter(subscription=subscriptions_1month).annotate(Count('user', distinct=True)).count()
    user_subscriptions_1year = UserSubscription.objects.filter(subscription=subscriptions_1year).annotate(Count('user', distinct=True)).count()
    user_subscriptions_3years = UserSubscription.objects.filter(subscription=subscriptions_3year).annotate(Count('user', distinct=True)).count()

    income_per_subscription_1month = Subscription.objects.get(plan_name='1 Month').price * UserSubscription.objects.filter(subscription=subscriptions_1month).count()
    income_per_subscription_1year = Subscription.objects.get(plan_name='1 Year').price * UserSubscription.objects.filter(subscription=subscriptions_1year).count()
    income_per_subscription_3years = Subscription.objects.get(plan_name='3 Years').price * UserSubscription.objects.filter(subscription=subscriptions_3year).count()
    
    total_income = income_per_subscription_1month + income_per_subscription_1year + income_per_subscription_3years

    return render (request, "stats_home.html", locals())
```

An finally, I'm trying to make a simple calculation (total income - total costs) but I'm unable to do this inside the template, as far as I could see and my research led me.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load has_group %}

{% block title %} Statistics Home {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="card border-dark mb-4" id="profil">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-white">Total number of users subscribed to the site:</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
         {{total_users}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card border-dark mb-4" id="profil">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-white">Total number of users per subscription type:</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
        <br>1 Month: {{user_subscriptions_1month}}
        <br>1 Year: {{user_subscriptions_1year}}
        <br>3 Years: {{user_subscriptions_3years}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card border-dark mb-4" id="profil">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-white">Costs:</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            {% for cost in costs %}
            <p>Infrastructure Costs: {{cost.costs_infra}}</p>
            <p>Salary Costs: {{cost.costs_salary}}</p>
            <p>Total Costs: {{cost.calculate_costs}}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card border-dark mb-4" id="profil">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-white">  Total Income: </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          {{total_income}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card border-dark mb-4" id="profil">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-white">  Benefits/Loss: </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            Benefits/Loss: {{total_income - cost.calculate_costs}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

By doing {{total_income - cost.calculate_costs}} i get an error

Could not parse the remainder: ' - cost.calculate_costs' from 'total_income - cost.calculate_costs'

The thing is that i can get the total costs with {{cost.calculate_costs}} and the total income with {{total_income}}, but somehow i'm unable to make a simple substraction inside the template.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please add the code you tried for the template and the results you got

Comment: I've tried the following amongst many other things (ommiting the html):

Benefits/Loss: {{total_income - cost.calculate_costs}}

I'm able to get total costs with {{cost.calculate_costs}} and total income with {{total_income}}

Comment: We need to see how you integrate all the stuff in you html code

Comment: You should Edit your first post accordingly, and add also related view ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to access `cost.calculate_costs` outside of loop `{% for cost in costs %}`. Since `cost` is not declared, you are getting this error. On top of that, django doesn't natively support calculation in template - reason is that it's best to keep logic entirely in views and leave only presentation in templates. There is however [addition filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#add), but you still need to calculate `total_costs`.

Your solution is calculate `total_profit` in view:

```
def stats_home(request):
    ...
    total_costs = sum(cost.calculate_costs for cost in costs)
    total_profit = total_income - total_costs

    return render (request, "stats_home.html", locals())
```

```
<div class="card border-dark mb-4" id="profil">
    <h5 class="card-header bg-dark text-white"> Benefits/Loss: </h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        Benefits/Loss: {{ total_profit }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did the trick, what I was missing was the loop indeed. Thanks a lot, this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is, rather than doing calculation in templates do it in views as it is **recommended not to do this in templates** as it will **decrease the performance** of the website **do this instead:**

views.py

```
variable = total_income - total_costs
context = {"variable":variable}
return render(request, "stats_home.html", locals(), context)
```

Comment: I though of this but my problem is that my total_costs is calculated by the @property on the model, so somehow I'm not able to get the total_costs inside my view (or at least I have not yet found a way of doing this)

Comment: see this it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541874/how-can-i-access-django-model-property-from-view

Comment: add that serializer

Comment: you could do that calculation in the view itself rather than using property...